# export Bigquery results to GCS based on value of a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've been using the following code to export BQ result to GCS.

```
  export_query = f"""
      EXPORT DATA
      OPTIONS(
        uri='{uri}',
        format=format,
        overwrite=true,
        compression='GZIP')
      AS {query}"""
  client.query(export_query, project=project).result()
```

Now I need to split a large table base on the value of a particular column, and then export each part separately , i.e.

```
query_k = """
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = k
"""
```

for k = 1,2,3...N

I can do it by running N queries, but that seems to be very slow and consume a lot of resources. I am wondering if it is possible to accomplish the task with one single query.

Comment: Hi @Ryan, can you confirm whether your table is partitioned or not?